# Обновление отдельного блока fsockopen

Tags: php, javascript

Суть такая: есть отдельный блок, в нем функция `fsockopen`. Если сервер, который пингуется, функция пытается весь тайм аут пингануть, его что приводит к зависанию страницы.
Т.е. необходимо сделать, чтобы изначально был блок с типом (загрузка... итд). А как `fsockopen` пропингует, выводился бы его результат.

Comment: мозг сломал (
попробуйте, ради эксперимента, использовать терминологию осознанно, а не тупо повторять и неправильно склонять прикольное словечко, и возможно люди начнут Вас понимать.

Comment: т.е. необходимо js скрипт который подгружал уделенно php скрипт который будит отображен только через опр. время

Comment: алгоритм следующий: подгружаем необходимый контент аяксом, запускаем таймер, выводим текст.